# Why can't my WebAPI service call find part of the path to a folder via IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core WebAPI 2.1 services. I created a structure in my deployment folder like below. (I'm using IIS.) I want to access `MyVariables.json` from all services. But, it gave this error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\wwwroot\MyProject\Shared\MyVariables.json'.

But that folder and path do exist. I'm trying by this code from my C# service.

```
using (StreamReader file =File.OpenText(@"../Shared/MyVariables.json"))
{
}
```

What can be the reason of this?

**My publish folder design**

```
-wwwroot
  -MyProject
     +Service1
     +Service2
     +Service3
     +Service4
     -Shared
        MyVariables.json
```

Answer (score 1):

IIS runs with an identity that is configured in the App pool.

Directory access rights must be given to the identity used to run the App pool.

Start **inetmgr.exe** to configure IIS,find App Pool identity and then configure access in file explorer.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelDURIN. But when I tried adding `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` from security tab of `shared` folder from `properties` , then it gave me error **An object named "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" cannot be found** on `CheckNames` button click.

Comment: Just added a link, hope it can help.

Comment: In that post, it say write "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" .But, it gave me above error. I'll try another way. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the identity of your pool in the management of IIS ?